# How to troubleshoot user error messages?

Tags: developer-console, error-messages

What is the best way to troubleshoot errors encountered by users? Normally, I try to reproduce the error in an System administrator User Account to see the output in the Developer Console. This way, I can look at every validation rules, workflow, triggers and apex classes executed. In this case, since the error is only happening with certain users without access to the console, it's a lot harder to find, because I cannot rely on the console.

It seems to be a custom error message (so probably from a Trigger/Validation rule). Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ask the user to Grant Login Access, so that you can log in as them.
2. Go to Setup/Monitoring/Debug Logs and set a debug watch on the user in question.
3. Log in as that user and recreate the error.
4. Log out of that user and view the Debug Logs.

If that user is listed in Debug Logs, their logs will also show up in Developer Console. To monitor what's happening simultaneously, you can use Chrome Users or different browsers to be logged in as the user in one session and Administrator with Dev Console open in another session.